# How to cut a number into digits and add them to each other in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

For example 2211 needs to display 6 but I can't find a command that helps me with it.
I have already tried with cut but that can only cut one at a time.

Comment: please update the question to show the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code; also, is this number in a variable or a file? do you have just the single number to sum up or a list of numbers? do you need to do anything else with the sum once you've obtained it (or just print to stdout)?

Answer (score 2):

Works in Debian. Try this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

number="2211"

result=0
for (( i=0; i<${#number}; i++ )); do
   echo "number[${i}]=${number:$i:1}"
  result=$(( result + ${number:$i:1} ))
done

echo "result = ${result}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `while` + `read` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str=2211

while IFS= read -rd '' -n1 addend; do
  ((sum+=addend))
done < <(printf '%s' "$str")

declare -p sum
```

---

If your bash is new enough, instead of `declare`

```
echo "${sum@A}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash` version 5.2 (the most recent version to this date):

```
shopt -s patsub_replacement
n=2211
echo $((${n//?/+&}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Math variant probably there are more elegant variants

```
sum=0
num=2211
n=${#num}

for ((i=n-1; i>=0; i--)); {
    a=$((10**i))
    b=$((num/a))
    sum=$((sum+b))
    num=$((num-(b*a)))
    echo $i $a $b $num $sum
}
3 1000 2 211 2
2 100 2 11 4
1 10 1 1 5
0 1 1 0 6

$ echo $sum
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) way to do it with arithmetic instead of string manipulation:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

declare -i num=2211 sum=0
while (( num > 0 )); do
    sum+=num%10
    num=num/10
done
echo "$sum"
```